# Unlike chrome Unable to create multiple instance of sidepanel while creating extension for edge browser

Tags: browser

I am creating sidepanel based extension for browsers(Chrome & Edge). I am able to create multiple instance sidepanel for chrome (Different contents populated for different tabs). But unlike chrome, In Edge same content getting populated to all tabs.

I am able to create multiple instance sidepanel for chrome (Different contents populated for different tabs).
Like in chrome, In Edge browser based on tab I need to populate content into sidepanel.

Steps I followed for creating sidepanel:

Step 1: "permissions": ["sidePanel", "tabs"]

Step 2:  Allows users to open the side panel by clicking on the action toolbar icon

````
    chrome.sidePanel
   .setPanelBehavior({ openPanelOnActionClick: true })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, info, tab) => {
     if (!tab.url) return;
        const url = new URL(tab.url);
     await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
      tabId,
      path: 'sidepanel.html',
      enabled: true
     });
    });```

Note: Same code will work for both browsers(Chrome & Edge) for opening sidepanel. But unlike chrome,Edge Browser creating single instance of sidepanel for all tabs. So same data is populating for all tabs sidepanel.
````